# How can I waterproof a sloped basement floor?

Tags: flooring

I have a basement built in '65 with a sloped floor to drain under the washer. Leveling the floor is out of the question. I currently have carpet on the washer side and LVP on the flat living side.

I want one continuous waterproof covering on the floor. What floor covering can I use?

Comment: Epoxy, perhaps, but if you have LVP on the living side, that seems like a downgrade for that side. Upgrade for the carpet on the washer side (carpet - floor drain - umm, wow?)

Comment: I tried to make your background and question a little more clear. Please make sure that it still represents what you're after.

Comment: Does painting the concrete floor with a wear-resistant floor paint suit your requirements ?